# Service Fabric ASP.NET core website stops working after running for multiple days

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have an Azure Service Fabric cluster. With a statefull service and stateless service. 
The stateless service is an public facing asp.net core website. With multiple SQL connection strings and a connection to Azure Storage account.

When it runs for a longer time (multiple days), sometimes It hangs and I'm unable to identify the problem.

When I restart (from the SF cluster dashboard) the node running the service. It starts working again.

In the logs of the ASP.NET core application this was the last log. I don't know what

> System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.     at System.ArraySegment`1..ctor(T[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)     at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.RawUrlHelper.GetPath(Byte[] raw)     at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.RequestUriBuilder.DecodeAndUnescapePath(Byte[] rawUrlBytes)     at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.Request..ctor(RequestContext requestContext, NativeRequestContext nativeRequestContext)     at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.RequestContext..ctor(WebListener server, NativeRequestContext memoryBlob)     at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.AsyncAcceptContext.IOCompleted(AsyncAcceptContext asyncResult, UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes)  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener.MessagePump.d__22.MoveNext()

In the event viewer (Application, ServiceFabric Admin, Service Fabric Operational) of the node that was running the service was nothing out of the ordinary. This already happend multiple times.

Is there any place I can find more internal logging?
Or does anybody now where the error comes from?

My code to run asp.net core looks like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new WebListenerCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting WebListener on {url}");

                return new WebHostBuilder().UseWebListener()
                            .ConfigureServices(
                                services => services
                                    .AddSingleton(serviceContext))
                            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .UseStartup()
                            .UseApplicationInsights()
                            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                            .UseUrls(url)
                            .Build();
            }))
    };
```

Comment: You should put more trace logging of all processes (LogLevel Trace in your appsettings.json  config file)

Comment: @hugorgor I Use SeriLog and the loglevel is on Verbose.